# line spacing in flex box container div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why is there so much line spacing in flex box container? How can I adjust that? I was trying an example in w3schools and got this.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<h1>The flex-direction Property</h1>

<p>The "flex-direction: column;" stacks the flex items vertically (from top to bottom):</p>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Link:: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-direction_column
I tried `p {margin: 0}` but still no use. Please help with this. Thank You!!!

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. can you please elaborate?

Comment: what result do you expect about the line-height property here ? is it vertical  centering the text in the middle or the gray box in the middle or else ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you want to decrease the line spacing between the `p` tag if yes try to change `line-height:0` in `flex-container>div`

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The flex-direction Property</h1>

<p>The "flex-direction: column;" stacks the flex items vertically (from top to bottom):</p>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div><p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p></div>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

75 pixels is a very tall line height. Just change it to a smaller number such as "35px" or "1.2" and you'll see the difference.

```css
.flex-container > div {
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to get rid of the space is to remove or adjust the
`line-height: 75px;`

in `.flex-container>div`

you could remove it completely and the line height will be automatically adjusted to the browser default value which is close to `1.2` depending on your browser settings and font-size by your PC.

So the line height will be calculated as follows:

`line-height: 1.8975` ( roughly browser default value) `*` ( font-size you give to the element example `30px`)
it's really advised to use `1.2` when doing your math but yeah I just wanted to be as accurate as I can.

the height of that element will be `35.692px` after multiplying it with the line-height and font-size that's how your browser does it for you. But if you want more you can use more.

You could also use `percentage ( % )`

Here is a great page you could read about [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)